# Find element by ID within a String and then replace href value

Tags: javascript

I have the following string below (and multiple others for social networks) and I want to search for `social-twitter` and `social-facebook` and so forth (just ID targeting). I've heard that Regex isn't the best for parsing strings, but what I'm aiming to do here is search for the ID within the string (it will always be a link), and then replace the href with a value.

```
<li><a id="social-twitter" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
```

Now I know how to do this with front-end JavaScript targeting but the stack I'm using is Node/Express, and obviously I can't use `document.getElementById()` - any ideas? Scratching my head at this one.

Comment: You have the string server-side or client-side?

Comment: @JeffMatthews `Node/Express` - Server-side

Comment: @JeffMatthews server-side Jeff.

Comment: I have to run, but my thoughts on that problem is that it will be a pain and prone to errors.  If you can manipulate it client-side and then, get it to the server, you'd probably be much better off.

Comment: No worries @Jeff Matthews. Ideally I want to pass it through using Jade/Pug but the page I'm passing it to is not a Jade/Pug template, therefore I cannot. I could just use JavaScript on the front-end but it feels lazy to replace href values onload.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how versatile you need your solution to be, your options vary from basic string search and replace, to somewhat more robust regexes, to actually parsing the string as HTML and manipulating it using a library like JSDOM: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

If, for example, you're certain that the way those `<a>` tags are created always follow a similar pattern (i.e. `<a` followed directly by `id` property, followed directly by `href` property), then regex could work fine. But if these conditions are not certain, order of properties can change or other properties might be sprinkled in between, then you may have to opt for the more robust yet heavy-handed JSDOM solution. You'll be able to load your arbitrary HTML string into JSDOM, locate your element using `document.getElementById`, manipulate its properties, and then retrieve its updated `outerHTML`.

Comment: I'm looking for a server-side solution

Comment: Yes, JSDOM is server-side. Follow the link I've included in my answer and look at the examples.